# Emulating dynamic parameters with views

Tags: couchdb

Consider the following document structure...

```
{
    _id,
    _rev,
    postTitle,
    postBody
}
```

I'm writing a small nodeJS weblog application, where I'd like my URLs to reflect a posts title. For instance `/WebLog/Posts/View/Hello-World/`.

Since it's not possible to query CouchDB on anything but the _id property, does it make sense that I create a view for each post, in order to map a `postTitle` to an `_id`?

How would you go about querying other document-properties than the `_id`?

... Should I just forfeit and use MongoDB or MySQL instead? Am I asking too much of CouchDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are how you create indexes in CouchDB. To get documents by `postTitle`, use a view, the keys of which are `postTitle`s, and query it with `key=<title>` and `includedocs=true`.

```
{
    "views": {
        "by-post-title": {
            "map": "function(doc) { emit(doc.postTitle, null); }"
        }
    }
}
```

And the query: `GET /<db>/_design/<design>/_view/by-post-title?includedocs=true&key="Hello-World"`

Learn more about [CouchDB views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views) on the [CouchDB Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/).

Comment: This answer doesn't address the format of the resulting URLs mentioned in the question.  Add some content related to URL rewriting, and I'll vote it up. :)

Comment: @matt-passell: you are right that I did not address the URLs mentioned in the question, but they were just an example. My understanding was that those URLs were going to be served by the node.js app, which would query the CouchDB instance in turn.

Answer (score 1):

You've partially answered your own question, but yes you'll create a view, as mentioned by an answerer earlier.

```
"views": {
    "by-post-title": {
        "map": "function(doc) { 
            if(doc.postTitle){
                var titleURL = postTitle.split(" ").join("_");
                emit(doc.titleURL, {"body" : doc.postBody, "title": doc.postTitle);
            }

        }"
    }
}
```

now, 
http://yourcouchdb:yourport/yourdb/_design/by-post-title/_view/by-post-title?key="Hello_World" would return your postBody and postTitle.

Since your documents can contain other key:values, it is best not to return entire doc as the second parameter in emit calls.

Comment: Add } in emit method.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do a view for each post, that sounds painful to maintain.  However, you could use either Django (with Couchdb) or Couchapp, and both have good url rewriting abilities.  Also, look at this on the couchone website:

[couchdb rewrites in 0.11](http://blog.couchbase.com/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-one-nice-urls)